# How to display the checked radio button value in angularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to display selected radio button in the response div,if no option is selected that div will disappear.

> View Code:

```
<body ng-app="QuestionDisplayModule">
    <form>
        <div ng-controller="QuestionDisplayController">
            <div ng-repeat="q in questionsData" style="border:groove 1px green">
                <h4 style="color: darkmagenta">{{q.QText}}</h4>
                <p ng-repeat="a in q.answer1" style="color: cadetblue"><input type="radio"  name="answers" ng-model="options" value="{{a.option1}}" ng-checked="optionselected(options)" />{{a.option1}}</p>
                <div>your answer is :{{selectedoption}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

> Script Code:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module("QuestionDisplayModule", [])
        .controller("QuestionDisplayController", function ($scope, $http, $log) {

            $scope.optionselected = function (options)
            {
                $scope.selectedoption = options;
            }
            $http.get("displayQuestion").then(function(response)
            {
                $log.info(response);
                $scope.questionsData = response.data;
            })
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: You can just display  "your answer is : {{options}}"

Comment: any error showing?

Comment: no its not showing any error that is problem @Tanisha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use different **name** for each **question** otherwise you will can select only one option for all question and and should use different **model** for each **question** and no need to use `ng-checked="optionselected(options)"` to set selected option value because of you used `ng-model`.

you can try like this

```
<div ng-controller="QuestionDisplayController">
      <div ng-repeat="q in questionsData" style="border:groove 1px green">
        <h4 style="color: darkmagenta">{{q.QText}}</h4>
        <p ng-repeat="a in q.answer1" style="color: cadetblue">
          <input type="radio" name="answers+{{$parent.$index}}" ng-model="q.selectedAns" value="{{a.option1}}" />{{a.option1}}</p>
        <div ng-show="q.selectedAns">your answer is :{{q.selectedAns}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[**PLUNKER DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/2Xh9OX0fejpwdJEhJLkv?p=preview)

Comment: thank you @shaishab roy. am searching for this since 4 hours

Comment: colud you please suggest me how to pagination  using angularJs @shaishab roy

Comment: you can use angular ui bootstrap to implement pagination easily https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-show/ng-hide to display the div accordingly . Like

```
 <div ng-show="selectedoption != null">your answer is :{{selectedoption}}</div>
```

You can also use ng-if . Also you can check if selectedoption is blank .

Read :-  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Comment: first i need to display the selected option value that is not working fine @neda

Comment: <div ng-show="selectedoption != null">your answer is :{{selectedoption}}</div> if i use the when i select option for one question  it will show  for all questions with same option value @neda

Comment: Then you have to give scope value of the checkbox different for each repeat. try changing as ng-model="q.options"  and then do <div ng-show="q.options != null"

Comment: how i need to pass model value to controller <p ng-repeat="a in q.answer1" style="color: cadetblue"><input type="radio" name="answers" ng-model="{{a.option1}}" value="{{a.option1}}" ng-click="optionselected()" />{{a.option1}}</p> @neda

Comment: You dont need curly braces here just ng-model="a.option1"

Comment: i need to bind  that modal to $scope object know to show the response @ neda

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like did in the following fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/vishnusuresan/Lvc0u55v/6247/

simply use

```
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <body >
  <form>
    <div >
        <div  style="border:groove 1px green">
            <h4 style="color: darkmagenta"></h4>
            <p style="color: cadetblue"><input type="radio"  name="answers" ng-model="options" value="value1" ng-checked="optionselected(options)" /></p>
            <div>your answer is :{{options}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I don't know what you want to accomplish.

Comment: In view list of questions with options i.e one question with 4 options so when i select one option form the respective question that answer should display in "your answer is": like @Tanisha